# Filter a wordpress custom widget content

Tags: wordpress

How do I filter the content of my custom widget on WordPress? I'd tried googling it but most of the answers are using `widget_text`. What about using custom widgets?
I need to filter the content of all widgets dragged into a particular widget area. Content does not include the title, just the main content.

Answer (score 0):

You do not specify if you created the custom widget yourself (aka are owner/maintainer of the source) - as in that case you can modify the source directly, but a common way of interacting with the output before sending it to the browser is to use output buffering.

```
ob_start();
dynamic_sidebar( 'my-sidebar-id' );
$sidebar_output = ob_get_clean();
echo apply_filters( 'my_sidebar_output', $sidebar_output );
```

This quite interesting [post](http://philipnewcomer.net/2014/06/filter-output-wordpress-widget/) provides some alternative methods too - I've copied the above code from the page as it is a common approach. Obviously you could capture any type of widget / code snippet like that.

Note that the above filter is run not on individual widgets, but on the output of the entire sidebar, which contains the output from all widgets that are active there. To target a specific widget some further code (regex) will be required.

Comment: I already tried that approach before I made this thread. The scenario is, I want to edit the content of all widgets dragged into a particular widget area. And when I say content, the title is not included.